# what exactly does "useful fiction(s)" mean?

Tags: meaning

We used to use this phrase a fair amount in undergrad and I thought it was associated with some great thinker (like "thick description" / Geertz). But I don't think it is. What exactly does it mean? Maybe it just means what it says and has no technical / explicit meaning.

I / we used it in the context of an unvalidated fact that seemed to justify a policy or behavior but it was pretty vague (hence the question).

**Correct Meaning / Origin**
While the gist is inherent in the phrase, its meaning and origin is derived from Bertrand Russel's critique of Frege's theory of classes (search for useful fiction here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logicism )

Comment: I'd say it's a euphemism for ***propaganda***

Comment: It is a **useful fiction** (though cruel) to tell a child that the Scissorman will come and cut off its thumb if it sucks it. Another is "I am working late at the office" when going out with friends instead of going home.

Comment: Fictionalism is the view in philosophy according to which statements that appear to be descriptions of the world should not be construed as such, but should instead be understood as cases of "make believe", of pretending to treat something as literally true (a "useful fiction").
Wikipedia › wiki › Fictionalism
Fictionalism - Wikipedia

Comment: This use of the "countable" fiction has been around since the 16th century and has not changed its meaning. The adjective "useful" is not part of a phrase, but a simple modifier in its literal sense.

Answer (score 1):

I can illustrate this with a personal example. When working on a scientific problem I sometimes see the solution vaguely, make a rough attempt to assemble the data that might support my idea, try to test the idea with the data, find errors, correct them, go back to the problem to see if I still understand it, criticise my solution, go back to find more data, analyse them in different ways, go back to the solution and then the problem - and gradually by ranging around over all these things I form a line of argument that seems to progress inevitably with cold logic and objectivity through a sequence of problem, data, concepts, analysis and solution.

This line of argument is the one conventionally used to publish the work I did but in truth its "inevitable progression" is merely a *useful fiction* that justifies my writing the account in the conventional objective and understandable way. Few people would be interested in the confused, subjective and creative truth behind the *useful fiction* of the inevitable, coldly objective march of science.

Comment: I wonder if a useful fiction is like a pedagogic lie?

Comment: Close, very close. Your comment reminds me of early secondary school science demonstrations in which the matter was subtly falsified to give the appearance of the correct method and the illuminating result: a pedagogic lie - a statement that is false, but which nevertheless leads the child's mind towards a more accurate explanation. And it worked! :)

Comment: Terry Pratchett et.al use "lies-to-children' in The Science of the Discworld  for this very concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children